# shortest path between all nodes matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, shortest-path

I would be grateful if you could help me with this:

I have a matrix `A(50,50)` in which I want to show the movement of an organism. At first the organism is everywhere in the matrix and step by step it shrinks,forming "veins". I have to say that it moves towards to the smell of food. I have to form a cross pattern, so I choose 9 nodes and put the maximum value 100 (which are supposed to be the food sources).

At first I create a matrix full of zeros and then I define where the food sources are, i.e. `A(11,25)=100`, `A(18,25)=100`, `A(25,25)=100` etc..

All the other cells of the matrix take values lower than 100 accordingly to an equation,that represents the movement of this organism. The problem is that although the organism moves with optimization, I can't form exactly a cross. I tried to measure its mass near the food sources,but in the center it gives me a result more like a rhombus.

So,I was thinking of this:
After measuring the mass of each cell in the matrix, like I already did,to measure and compare the distances between every node where we have mass and the central food source `A(25,25)` and keep the lowest values, so that the form can be formed.

If there is an alternative solution,please enlighten me!

Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you illustrate your problem by an example, please?

Comment: I edited the question,hoping this is more clear